# Extract text between keywords in a file using perl

Tags: perl

How can i extract text between keywords?
The text is saved in a txt or json file.
The input is this. "Adapt to the environment and project challenges\nAbility to manage issues, communications and influencing skills,Passion for great technology and user experience\nExceptional organizational skills,"

The keywords are "ability","skills" and "experience". The output should be the text that is between those keywords. In this example the output should be:

to manage issues, communications and influencing
Passion for great technology and user experience\nExceptional organizational

The regex must be ready to accept 4 or 5 keywords. Is it possible?

I used the code below but it only works if the text is in the program instead of being in a txt file.
This would only work for 2 keywords. I need several.

```
$file = 'C:\Users\Acer Nitro\Desktop\perl\sim.txt';

open(SESAME, $file);
while(<SESAME>)
{
    $text .= $_;
}

close(SESAME);
print $text;

($re=$text)=~s/((\bskill\b)|(\bability\b)|.)/${[')','']}[!$3]\Q$1\E${['(','']}[!$2]/gs;
@$ = (eval{/$re/},$@);
print join"\n",@$ unless $$[-1]=~/unmatched/;
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1418208/edit) and add extract of input file and expected result. And explain what your regex is suposed to do. Also, format properly your question.

Comment: There are many problems with the last three lines; `($re=$test)` doesn't make any sense here; why do you use `eval /$re/` ? Anyway this is  a programming question, it belongs to stackoverflow.com ...

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to change your regular expression. "\ability" and "\skill" is probably not what you want. "\a" is the character for "bell" and "\s" is the matching for a white space character.

The text parts, which you want to capture, can be matched with a appropriated part of the regular expression enclosed in parentheses. When the whole RE has found a match, the partial matched parts can be accessed using $1, $2, etc. Perhaps... '(\w+)\s+(ability|skill)\s+(\w+)'

Comment: I made some changes, the "\a" and "\s" should be a "\b". It was a mistake. Check the question again, please

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of error in your script, I've rewrotten and simplified it<

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

# file to search
my $file = 'C:\Users\Acer Nitro\Desktop\perl\sim.txt';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "unable to open '$file' for reading: $!";
# read whole file in a single string
undef $/;
my $full = <$fh>;
# search text between keywords
my @found = $full =~ /\b(?:ability|skills|experience)\b\R?\K(.+?)(?=\b(?:ability|skills|experience)\b)/gsi;
# dump the result
print Dumper\@found;
```

**Output for given example:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          ' to manage issues, communications and influencing ',
          ',Passion for great technology and user ',
          'Exceptional organizational '
        ];
```

**Regex explanation:**

```
/                       # regex delimiter
    \b                  # word boundary
    (?:                 # non capture group
        ability         # literally
      |                 # OR
        skills          # literally
      |                 # OR
        experience      # literally
    )                   # end group
    \b                  # word boundary
    \R?                 # optional linebreak
    \K                  # forget all we have seen until this position
    (.+?)               # group 1, the text we want
    (?=                 # positive lookahead
        \b              # word boundary
        (?:             # non capture group
            ability     # literally
          |             # OR
            skills      # literally
          |             # OR
            experience  # literally
        )               # end group
        \b              # word boundary
    )                   # end lookahead
/gsi                    # delimiter, global; dot matches newline; case insensitive
```